# SSRS reports deployment in production server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, reporting-services

We have 50 SSRS report created in SharePoint 2010 integrated mode. Now we want to move these 50 SSRS reports to production server.

1. Do we need to create script for this deployment (of report in integrated mode)?
2. Can we take .rdl & .rds files to prod server and then change configuration. will it work?
3. what is correct way to deploy integrated mode reports to production?
4. From where we will get scripting?
5. Is there any difference if reports are built either in Integrated mode or in separate mode?

In this case .rdl files are stored in report library. What happens if files are stored in Report server. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options for deploying reports to a different server. I've actually written a [blog post](http://blog.westmonroepartners.com/get-the-most-out-of-your-data-three-tips-for-using-ssrs-reports-in-sharepoint/) that covered this (see tip #3) - there are three options.

1. Drag and drop the RDL files onto the server.

   This probably isn't going to work since you'll need to update your data connection paths,etc, etc. I think this is what you meant in question #2 - yes, it will work, but it's a pain.

   2. Deploy the reports using Visual Studio - you can use the Deploy feature in SSRS Data Tools to publish reports automatically to an environment after setting up the configuration properly. This is what I would recommend assuming that all your reports are going to a single folder - you'll only need to make a single configuration.
   3. Use custom code to deploy the reports. This requires using the [SSRS Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787.aspx) to deploy items and configure them, but it will work. Specifically you're going to want to use the CreateCatalogItem function and then some other methods around updating the data connections on the reports.

I wouldn't recommend #3 unless you have a situation where you'll be deploying these 50 reports to different sites on a regular basis and want to automate it all - #2 is the best use case for standard deployments.

I know this is a pretty old question but hopefully this helps anyone who's facing this issue!